# Unable to assign a CLLocationCoordinate2D to another CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I am getting the following error:

```
Assigning to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D *' from incompatible type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'; take the address with &
```

At the following line below:

```
 locationMapViewController.centerOfMap = coordinate;



- (IBAction) btnLocateAddress
{

    if (!self.geocoder) {
        self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    }


    [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.address.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

            self.address.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];

            if ([placemark.areasOfInterest count] > 0) {
                NSString *areaOfInterest = [placemark.areasOfInterest objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSLog(@"Area of Interest: %@",areaOfInterest);
            }



        //lets push the new map screen
            LocationMapViewController *locationMapViewController = [[LocationMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationMapViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            locationMapViewController.title=@"Your Property Listing";
            locationMapViewController.centerOfMap = coordinate;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationMapViewController animated:YES]; 


        }
    }];


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you all. You are assigning a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` value (see NO POINTER) to a pointer ( `CLLocationCoordinate2D *` ) You can use & to get the adress of a variable. Also known as `pointer` . So you can either  do `locationMapViewController.centerOfMap = &coordinate;` or set the `latitude` and `longitude` values directly.

Cheers,

George